# Spring one ModelAttribute in several Controller

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jspx, apache-tiles

I develop in Spring MVC + Apache Tiles + JSPX in my system.

I would like to put login form in every page. In the login process I would like to use `@ModelAttribute("loginModel")` LoginDTO

In Spring docs page I red that I must define a method in every controller, where I want to display that model like this:

```
@ModelAttribute("loginModel")
public LoginDTO loginModel() {
   return new LoginDTO();
}
```

Is there any way that I define it only one controller, and works in every page where I write the login Form jsp?

Thanks your answare!

Comment: voting to reopen as the duplicate question was deleted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Spring 3.2 or later you can use the new [@ControllerAdvice](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) annotation. 
From the documentation of [@ModelAttribute](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods):

> @ModelAttribute methods can also be defined in an @ControllerAdvice-annotated class and such methods apply to all controllers. The @ControllerAdvice annotation is a component annotation allowing implementation classes to be autodetected through classpath scanning.

In your case, I guess it would look something like:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerAdvice {

    @ModelAttribute("loginModel")
    public LoginDTO loginModel() {
        return new LoginDTO();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make abstract controller with your loginModel and extends it for each controller you want to use login form in, this abstract controller should be without @Controller, all sub classes have to contain @Controller.